# Firebase & Alamofire Url TableViewCell image load Issue Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift4

I am settiing an image onto a `tableViewCell` with `Alamofire`

```
let messageImage = cell?.viewWithTag(6) as! UIImageView
messageImage.image = nil
messageImage.af_setImage(withURL: photoUrl! as URL)

return cell
```

I am appending each cell item to an array using `Firebase`:

```
ref.child("messages").child(ticker.current).queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: {snapshot in

            let snapDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let photoUrl = snapDict?["photo_url"] as? String ?? ""

            messageArray.insert(messageCellStruct(photoUrl: photoUrl), at: 0)
         })
```

Then I am updating the image on the **Same Exact URL** with `FirebaseStorage`

When I re-call the cell `ViewController` that the `TableViewCell` is in, the image is not changed on the first couple of cells. But as I scroll to older cells the image is updated:

```
messageArray.removeAll()
tableView.reload()
```

If I rebuild the app all cell images are how they are supposed to be.

I am assuming this is because of an Observer error or Im not **removing the observer.** I really dont know.

**1.)** The cells share the **same exact URL** im just changing the data.

**2.)** It seems to be only working when a cell hasnt loaded yet(or been assigned).

**3.)** It works perfectly fine after I rebuild and run the app.

[image]

Maybe I need to clear the Alamofire cach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Alamofire` saves image cache locally.

Because I was changing data to the **Same Exact URL** I had to remove the cache.

```
 UIImageView.af_sharedImageDownloader.imageCache?.removeAllImages()

 UIImageView.af_sharedImageDownloader.sessionManager.session.configuration.urlCache?.removeAllCachedResponses()
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to set the old image to nil before you set the image in `messageImage.af_setImage(withURL: photoUrl! as URL)`.

Cell's are supposed to get cleaned up before they are reused: [Apple -PrepareForReuse](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse)  but Apple also says:

> For performance reasons, you should only reset attributes of the cell
>   that are not related to content, for example, alpha, editing, and
>   selection state. The table view's delegate in
>   tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) should always reset all content when
>   reusing a cell.

That basically means you Shouldn't set your imageView's image to nil in `prepareForReuse` BUT if you sub classed the cell you can create a function inside the subclass and in `cellForRowAtIndePath` call it before you run `messageImage.af_setImage(withURL: photoUrl! as URL)`. Example Below:

Create subclass for cell and name it MyCustomCell

```
class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var messageImage: UIImageView!

    func setImageToNil(){
        messageImage.image = nil
        // I don't use AlamoFire and don't know anything about it but if they have something to set the imageView's image to nil you can also try using that instead
    }
}
```

Inside your tableView's `cellForRowAtIndexPath` cast the cell then call `setImageToNil()` before you run `messageImage.af_setImage`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     // 0. cast the cell as MyCustomCell
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell

     // 1. call the setImageToNil() method and whatever image is inside messageImage will get set to nil every time the cell is reused
     cell.setImageToNil()

     // 2. the new image should always appear because the old image was set to nil
     cell.messageImage.af_setImage(withURL: photoUrl! as URL)

     return cell
}
```

Comment: Update I am already doing that. I cant figure it out. It changes when i post an update to the firebase but it wont change the old images.

Comment: I think Alamofire caches the image locally and that might be the reason. I need to do more research.

Comment: Possibly alamofire is caching and somehow showing old images??? Have you tried SDWebImage? It works really well https://cocoapods.org/pods/SDWebImage

Comment: Try this SO q&a, someone else had the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33467263/4833705

Comment: I feel like iI would have the same issue it will store it locally. I think i found my problem. I need to clear the cache.

Comment: That what that answer says

Comment: Trying those right now no luck yet. Still researching.

Comment: Good luck! 

Comment: Thanks figured it out.

Comment: np, you should post the answer so the next person who comes across the issue can use your code to resolve it. Have a nice evening :)