# Reset Alamofire cache of a Specific URL Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swift4, alamofireimage

`Alamofire` saves images to cache.

Rather then resetting all cache images like this.

```
 UIImageView.af_sharedImageDownloader.imageCache?.removeAllImages()
 UIImageView.af_sharedImageDownloader.sessionManager.session.configuration.urlCache?.removeAllCachedResponses()
```

I would like to reset the cache of a `specific URL` in `Swift 4`

How can i accomplish this?

Comment: try this code https://iswift.org/playground?47BpLq&v=3 ، If it works correctly you have to tell me to add the answers

Comment: your not doing anything with the variable cache

Comment: Make sure the image url works fine :/

Comment: And no your code doesnt work but that is the kind of thing im looking for just cant figure out how to do it in swift 4. The URL works perfectly fine.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33481293/9315978

Comment: None of those work for me.